# avoid loading specific class in hierarchy with sqlalchemy query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to load an entity via a sqlalchemy query while explicitly avoiding loading a specific class of entity as a field on any instance of any child of my loaded entity.  Take the below data model:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

base = declarative_base()


class Parent(base):
    __tablename__ = 'Parent'
    uid = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)


class Child(base):
    __tablename__ = 'Child'
    uid = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Parent.uid'))
    parent = relationship('Parent', backref="children")


class OtherChild(base):
    __tablename__ = 'OtherChild'
    uid = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Parent.uid'))
    parent = relationship('Parent', backref="other_children")


class Bicycle(base):
    __tablename__ = 'Bicycle'
    uid = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    child_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Child.uid'))
    child = relationship('Child', backref="bicycles")

    child_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('OtherChild.uid'))
    child = relationship('OtherChild', backref="bicycles")
```

If I do a `Parent.query.all()` then I'm going to get back any `Child` or `OtherChild` objects which are in those `Parent` objects in the `children` and `other_children` fields, respectively. Further, I'll get any `Bicycle` objects which are embedded inside either the `Child` or `OtherChild` objects.

I wish to do a `query` on `Parent` which explicitly avoids loading any `Bicycle` objects on any children regardless how deep they may be in the data structure.

**Update:**

It is possible to constrain the children returned in a query using `options(contains_eager(<pathtoclass>))`. For example (not tested but pretty sure it would work):

```
query = query.outerjoin(Child, primaryjoin.expression).\
    options(contains_eager('children'))
```

However, this requires explicitly describing the `options` for each path. In a circumstance with hundreds of valid options this becomes onerous. I would prefer to just express something like `query.contains_eager(CLASS)`.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/loading_relationships.html#controlling-loading-via-options), relationships use lazy loading by default. No `Bicycle` objects will load until you directly access the relationship attribute.

Since the relationships appear to be unidirectional from `Bicycle` to `Child` and from `Bicycle` to `OtherChild`, you shouldn't have to worry about loading `Bicycle` objects unless you specifically query for them.

Comment: I'm suggesting using something like `contains_eager`, I'll update the question.